# Bound on Distance Between Iterates of Lipschitz Function at a Point

Tags: dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions, upper-lower-bounds, discrete-time

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $L$-[Lipschtiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) continuous function and for every positive integer $n$ define
$$
x^n = f(x^{n-1}) \mbox{ and } x^0=x,
$$
for some fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.  Then for $n<m$, positive integers, is there a (reasonable) bound on
$$
\|x^n-x^m\| ,
$$
as a function of $L$, $n$, and $m$?

Comment: Hint: telescopic series $x^n-x^m=(x^n-x^{n+1})+(x^{n+1}-x^{n+2})+\cdots+(x^{m-1}-x^m)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: telescopic series $x^n-x^m=(x^n-x^{n+1})+(x^{n+1}-x^{n+2})+\cdots+(x^{m-1}-x^m)$ gives you
$$\Vert x^n-x^m\Vert\leq\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}L^i\Vert x-x^1\Vert=\frac{L^n-L^m}{1-L}\Vert x-x^1\Vert.$$

This bound is tight for $f(x)=Lx$, $x^0=1$

Comment: Is there a reasonable lower-bound depending on $n,m$ (non-constantly)?

Comment: @AIM_BLB Not really. A constant function is $L$-Lipschitz but $\Vert x^n-x^m\Vert=0$ for $n,m\geq 1$.

Comment: Fair but suppose non-constant (or else like you said its trivial)